# Reading an array 'from left to right', binary heap priority

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a simple piece of code that reads an array of values. On user input, 2 values are compared and are set up as a binary heap. The method is described here:

http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/MethodEngineering/TheBinarySearchTreeAsRequirementsPrioritizationTechnique

[image]

> Peter writes each requirement on a piece of paper and piles them. In a
>   second step, he takes the first requirement (requirement 5) from the
>   pile and puts it on top of a white board. Then he takes another
>   requirement (requirement 7) from the pile and the group discusses
>   which requirement (requirement 5 or 7) is more important. Finally they
>   agree that requirement 7 is less important than requirement 5. Peter
>   puts requirement 7 to the bottom left of requirement 5. Then he takes
>   another requirement (requirement 4) and the group compares this again
>   with requirement 5. After having concluded that it is also less
>   important than requirement 5, they compare it with requirement 7. They
>   agree that it is more important than requirement 7. Peter puts
>   requirement 4 to the bottom right of requirement 7. The group repeats
>   this procedure for all requirements on the pile. In the end, they have
>   created a BST of all requirements on the white board. Finally, Peter
>   creates a list of all requirements in prioritized order. For this he
>   starts noting down the number of the requirement the most right of the
>   BST (requirement 6). He continues with the requirement closest to it
>   (requirement 8), then the next one closest to this (requirement 10),
>   and so forth. The final prioritization order of all requirements is
>   (from high to low) 6, 8, 10, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, and 1. The list of
>   prioritized requirements can now be used to select the requirements to
>   be implemented in the next release.

```js
tets()
function tets() {
  var tasks = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

  //root
  var root = [tasks[0]];


  function prio(q, step) {

    //compare with step[0], now I just say 'random' more or less important for this demo;  
    var res = Math.random() > .5;

    if (res) {
      if (!step[2]) {
        step[2] = [q];

      } else {

        prio(q, step[2])
      }
    } else {

      if (!step[1]) {
        step[1] = [q]

      } else {
        prio(q, step[1])
      }
    }


  }



  for (var i = 1; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    prio(tasks[i], root)
  }
  console.log(root)
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"> </pre>
```

As you see the array is build up like the binary tree in the image. every element is build up like an array of 3: [0] = the name, [1](http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/MethodEngineering/TheBinarySearchTreeAsRequirementsPrioritizationTechnique) is the node on the left, en [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZALU.jpg) is the node on the right.

The main question is:

How can I have javascript traverse this tree and get the most RIGHT element as highest priority, and the most left as lowest?

Comment: That's a simple in order traversal of your tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can use [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

The order of the execution is important, first look for right children and traverse, display the node information, then iterate the left children.

```js
function traverse(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a[2] && traverse(a[2]);
        a[0] && document.write(a[0] + '<br>');
        a[1] && traverse(a[1]);   
    }
}

var root = [5, [7, [2, [1]], [4]], [9, [3], [8, [10], [6]]]];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(root, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
traverse(root);
```

Comment: Result is not correct: 6, 10, 8, 3, 9, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5 instead of 6, 8, 10, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1

Comment: Left side is more priotorized then the main element (e.g. 7 more prio than 5 in OP example)

Comment: you see the random element, which makes comparisons hard?

Comment: I tested your code using a static list with OPs example. So no, not random.

Comment: As far as my testing goes on the random string, drawing it on paper, and checking with your results, it is spot on. 

Quite impressive, thank you!

ps I did not know the && trick, makes it a lot more readable.




@Argon,  6,8,10 is the correct result here?

Comment: @Riël She changed the code since my comments, the result was faulty at first.

Comment: @ArgOn, I see, agreed. 

I do hope you agree the final solution is a nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I wrote this function:

JavaScript

```
function getFlatArray(array, priority) {
  var result = [];
  getFlatArrayRecursive(array, priority, result);
  return result;
}

function getFlatArrayRecursive(array, priority, result) {
  for(var i = 0; i < priority.length; i++) {
    var currentItem = array[priority[i]];
    if(currentItem != null) {
      if(Array.isArray(currentItem)) {
        getFlatArrayRecursive(currentItem, priority, result);
      } 
      else {
        result.push(currentItem);
      }
    }
  }
}

var priority = [2, 0, 1];
var root = [
   5,
   [
      7,
      [
         2,
         [1]
      ],
      [4]
   ],
   [
      9,
      [3],
      [
         8,
         [10],
         [6]
      ]
   ]
];
var results = getFlatArray(root, priority);
console.log(results); //[6, 8, 10, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1]
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/nwg5122x/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the tree state, and analyze which branch is higher/lower by using a sort method at each branch level until the whole tree is has been traversed.  Store the highest/lowest values in a global var outside of the function.  This should work even when the current branch level is more than a binary system.  Here is an example of what the code inside of the recursive function might look like for each level:

```
// example tasks at this branch level
var tasks = [["a", 1, 2], ["b", 0, 1], ["c", 3, 0], ["d", 4, 1]];

// make a copy so that original task list is maintained
var tasksCopy = tasks;

// sort the array from lowest left node to highest left node      
var sortedLowToHigh = tasksCopy.sort(function(a, b) { 
     return a[1] - b[1];
});

// the lowest value will be at the first array element
var highestPriorityTask = sortedLowToHigh[0][1];

// sort the arry from highest right node to lowest right node
var sortedHighToLow = tasksCopy.sort(function(a, b){
     return b[2] - a[2];
});

// the highest value will be at the first array element
var lowestPriorityTask = sortedHighToLow[0][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is the nicest with respect to line of code:

```js
function traverse(n) {
  return !Array.isArray(n) 
        ? (isNaN(n) ? [] : [n]) 
        : [...traverse(n[2]), ...traverse(n[0]), ...traverse(n[1]), ];
}
var root = [5, [7, [2, [1]], [4]], [9, [3], [8, [10], [6]]]];

console.log(traverse(root));
```